# How to change the links visiblitiy in tablet portrait mode using bootstrap/jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of links, only in tablet portrait mode, the first two links should be visible, then we have to display a menu icon, and on click of that rest of the links should appear inside the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
  <li class="hidden-sm"> link1 </li>
<li class="hidden-sm"> link2 </li>
<li class="hidden-sm"> link3 </li>
<li class="hidden-sm"> link4 </li>
<li class="hidden-sm"> link5 </li>
      <li class="dropdown hidden-lg hidden-md">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for jquery. Plain CSS is all you need.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    // CSS that should only be applied in portrait mode.
    // Hide your links here
}
```